# Add a note to notifications when updating Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api

When I manually modify a Google Calendar event in the web interface, it asks if I want to send a notification email to participants, and lets me add a message to the notification if I want:

[image]

I can't find a way to add such a message when updating an event through the API using either [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) or [patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch).

Is there an undocumented way to do this, or is it just an oversight in the API design?

Answer (score 0):

I verified in the [events insert method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) from the calendar API as well as the [Calendar class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) and I confirm that there is no option to do so.

just for good meassure I also checked the update and patch as well (even if you had already done so, just to make sure) and it is also not possible there.

I believe the only path forward here is to [request this to be a feature](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support#developer_product_feedback) and they could hopefully add this in the future.

Comment: If this is the case, the only way to get that feature is to delete it and then create a new identical one so that the popup happens.